# How to publish binary to specific folder using legacy VBScript templating

Tags: 2011, binary, vbscript

We are using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1, but with legacy VBScript templating. I want to publish some binary files to a specific folder. Can any one share the code to publish a binary using VBScript?

Answer (score 3):

In the old COM API's `TCMScriptAssistant` class, which has it's methods exposed to VBScript templates, there is an `AddBinary` method which I think you are looking for...

Documentation is as follows:

### AddBinary

## Summary

Writes binary data from a Multimedia Component to a temporary directory so that the publisher can retrieve the file and publish it to the Content Distributor at the location specified by the Structure Group.

## Usage

Use this function to publish a Binary file and obtain its URL.

## Visual Basic Syntax

```
Public Function AddBinary(
    ByVal component As Variant,
    ByVal structureGroup As Variant,
    Optional ByVal variantId As String = ""
) As String
```

## Parameters

component: A Multimedia Component or URI of a Multimedia Component of which the BinaryContent is retrieved.
structureGroup: A Structure Group or URI of a Structure Group that defines the directory to which the binary will be published.

## Remarks

Publishing fails if a file exists in the specified location that has the same name as the file you attempt to publish, and that is not an earlier published version of this Multimedia Component.

## Return value

Returns the (UTF-8) URL of the Binary file. In a UTF-8 URL, characters are first encoded in UTF-8 encoding and then standard URL encoding is applied. For example: the character `µ` (Unicode: `0x00B5`) is first encoded in UTF-8 as two bytes: `0xC2` and `0xB5`. After URL encoding this becomes: `%C2%B5`.

## Example

```
[% 
... 
Dim lStrFilename 

lStrFilename = AddBinary(lObjMultimediaComponent, lObjStructureGroup) 

'Use Filename to create image tag 
WriteOut "<img src=" & lstrfilename & " width=100 height=100>" 
%]
```